# SQL Server 2016 - get a list of all the index in a database which has online = ON

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I need to get a list of all the index in a database which has online = ON, is there a way to get from `sys.tables`?

I searched in `sys.indexes` & `sys.index_columns` but I'm not able to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

sys.indexes has an is_disabled column

```
  select name from sys.indexes where is_disabled = 0
```

Comment: I am looking for online, not is_disabled,
 is_disabled column stores index disable/enable value

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of the alter index statement which has an online=on option to rebuild indexes with a minimal of blocking?

Comment: using alter index I can change the value of online=ON, my requirement is,  to get all index in a database which has online = ON

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [Ola Hallengren's scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) and

- Set FragmentationLow / FragmentationMedium / FragementationHigh all to `INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE`
- Set Execute = `N`

This would print the rebuild online for every index where it would be able to be rebuilt (but won't actually rebuild it). This would exclude XML columns, spatial indexes, Indexes including LOB columns, etc... you can find a list of these on the web.